# Cannot resolve method append(int)

Tags: java, linked-list

The goal of the project is to create a calculator which will let the user choose which operation to use, which will then be solved and added to a linked list. The last option is to see the history which are past answers or solutions.

I'm quite new and this is a project I'm really trying to finish on my own but I have researched and still can't seem to quite understand what or how to fix. Please explain to me so that I can understand better! Also please comment on the design or flow of my code. Thanks!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class projectOne  {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int one = 0;
        int two = 0;
        int ans = 0;
        int selection = 0;

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        LinkedList l = new LinkedList();

        do{
            System.out.println("\nSelect an option: \n1. Addition \n2. Subtraction \n3. Multiplication \n4.Division \n5. See History");
            selection = scanner.nextInt();

      /*      if (selection >= 1 && selection <= 4) {
                System.out.println("\nEnter two numbers to be used in relevant calculation: ");
                one = scanner.nextDouble();
                two = scanner.nextDouble();
            }
      */
            switch(selection) {
                case 1:
                    System.out.println("Performing Addition. \nEnter first number: ");
                    one = scanner.nextInt();
                    System.out.println("Enter second number: ");
                    two = scanner.nextInt();
                    System.out.println(one + " + " + two + " = " + (one + two));
                    ans = one + two;
                    l.append(ans);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    System.out.println("Performing Subtraction. \nEnter first number: ");
                    one = scanner.nextInt();
                    System.out.println("Enter second number: ");
                    two = scanner.nextInt();
                    System.out.println(one + " - " + two + " = " + (one - two));
                    ans = one - two;
                    l.append(ans);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    System.out.println("Performing Multiplication. \nEnter first number: ");
                    one = scanner.nextInt();
                    System.out.println("Enter second number: ");
                    two = scanner.nextInt();
                    System.out.println(one + " * " + two + " = " + (one * two));
                    ans = one * two;
                    l.append(ans);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    System.out.println("Performing Division. \nEnter first number: ");
                    one = scanner.nextInt();
                    System.out.println("Enter second number: ");
                    two = scanner.nextInt();
                    System.out.println(one + " / " + two + " = " + (one / two));
                    ans = one / two;
                    l.append(ans);
                    break;
                case 5:
                    System.out.println("History: \n" + l);
                    break;
            }
        } while(selection != 6);
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no such method. Did you mean `add(..)` instead? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html

Comment: Try `add()` instead of `append()`

Comment: try to use some editor like eclipse to remove these kind of errors.

Comment: There is actually another class LinkedList which the professor gave for us to use and has an append method public void append(Node node) {
        //if head is empty then head is equal to node
        if (empty()) {
            head = node;
        } ...

I'm just very very new to coding so I really don't know how to exactly connect/relate(?) things

Comment: If the available method is `void append(Node node)`, then you have to give it a `Node` as an argument, not an `int`.  You need to 1) figure out how to "wrap" your `int` value (`ans`) in a new `Node` instance and 2) pass that `Node` instance to `append`.

Comment: updated that code @karinaabad

Comment: @karinaabad If you want use LinkedList which the professor gave for you, you do not `import the java.util.LinkedList`, you must `import your.professor.LinkedList` instead!

Answer (score 2):

[`LinkedList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) does not have method `append`, you can use `add`, `addLast`.

Also, please avoid using [`raw type`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it), use `LinkedList<Integer>` instead.